# Pandas resampling from months to weeks

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to downsample monthly data to weekly data and have a time series dataframe of months that looks like this:

```
             qty
PERIOD_NAME 
2017-09-01  49842.0
2017-10-01  27275.0
2017-11-01  29159.0
2017-12-01  51344.0
2018-01-01  19103.0
2018-02-01  23570.0
2018-03-01  45139.0
2018-04-01  25722.0
2018-05-01  22644.0
```

I've attempted using a resample to weeks like this:

```
tgt_item_by_445_wk = tgt_item_by_445_wk.resample('W').sum()
```

which yields:

```
             qty
PERIOD_NAME 
2017-09-03  49842.0
2017-09-10  0.0
2017-09-17  0.0
2017-09-24  0.0
2017-10-01  27275.0
2017-10-08  0.0
2017-10-15  0.0
2017-10-22  0.0
2017-10-29  0.0
```

I've tried interpolation, but I can't get what I am looking for, which is a fill of the unsampled (0's) with an even split of the first value like this:

```
              qty
PERIOD_NAME 
2017-09-03  12460.5
2017-09-10  12460.5
2017-09-17  12460.5
2017-09-24  12460.5
2017-10-01  5455.0
2017-10-08  5455.0
2017-10-15  5455.0
2017-10-22  5455.0
2017-10-29  5455.0
```

Is there some method using resample, fills and interpolation that allows this?

Comment: Is it as expected that the last month entry `2018-05-01  22644.0` is not got resampled and value not got split ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `asfreq` and `groupby`.

```
v = df.asfreq('W', method='ffill')
v /= v.groupby(v.index.strftime('%Y-%m')).transform('count')

                  qty
PERIOD_NAME          
2017-09-03   12460.50
2017-09-10   12460.50
2017-09-17   12460.50
2017-09-24   12460.50
2017-10-01    5455.00
2017-10-08    5455.00
2017-10-15    5455.00
2017-10-22    5455.00
2017-10-29    5455.00
2017-11-05    7289.75
2017-11-12    7289.75
2017-11-19    7289.75
2017-11-26    7289.75
2017-12-03   10268.80
2017-12-10   10268.80
2017-12-17   10268.80
2017-12-24   10268.80
2017-12-31   10268.80
2018-01-07    4775.75
2018-01-14    4775.75
2018-01-21    4775.75
2018-01-28    4775.75
2018-02-04    5892.50
2018-02-11    5892.50
2018-02-18    5892.50
2018-02-25    5892.50
2018-03-04   11284.75
2018-03-11   11284.75
2018-03-18   11284.75
2018-03-25   11284.75
2018-04-01    5144.40
2018-04-08    5144.40
2018-04-15    5144.40
2018-04-22    5144.40
2018-04-29    5144.40
```

This works well since your values are always on the first of each month. Alternatively, you may use

```
v /= v.groupby(v.qty).transform('count').values
```

for the second step.

Answer (score 4):

You need adjust your output a little bit by using `cumsum` with `groupby`

```
s=df.resample('W').mean()
s.groupby(s.qty.notnull().cumsum()).qty.transform(lambda x : x.sum()/len(x))
Out[166]: 
PERIOD_NAME
2017-09-03    12460.50
2017-09-10    12460.50
2017-09-17    12460.50
2017-09-24    12460.50
2017-10-01     5455.00
2017-10-08     5455.00
2017-10-15     5455.00
2017-10-22     5455.00
2017-10-29     5455.00
2017-11-05     7289.75
2017-11-12     7289.75
2017-11-19     7289.75
2017-11-26     7289.75
2017-12-03    10268.80
2017-12-10    10268.80
2017-12-17    10268.80
2017-12-24    10268.80
2017-12-31    10268.80
2018-01-07     4775.75
2018-01-14     4775.75
2018-01-21     4775.75
2018-01-28     4775.75
2018-02-04     5892.50
2018-02-11     5892.50
2018-02-18     5892.50
2018-02-25     5892.50
2018-03-04    11284.75
2018-03-11    11284.75
2018-03-18    11284.75
2018-03-25    11284.75
2018-04-01     5144.40
2018-04-08     5144.40
2018-04-15     5144.40
2018-04-22     5144.40
2018-04-29     5144.40
2018-05-06    22644.00
Freq: W-SUN, Name: qty, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I didn't see this when I posted. Nice answer (I have done something similar too)

Comment: @coldspeed no worry since we have different idea :-)